# What do the various "Update Depth" options in TortoiseSVN mean?

Tags: tortoisesvn

We have a large SVN tree, which includes folders which have branches. For each project in the tree I work on, I used to have a separate check out for each branch, as well as one for trunk.

What I'm trying to switch to now, is a single checkout, but with a selective set of folders. I would do this by using the "Update to revision" option, along with "Update Depth" set to "Working copy", and using "Choose items..." to select the folders I wanted. I would then also check "Make depth sticky".

The issue I have is that I can't quite figure out how to tell SVN that I no longer need a particular folder (for instance a branch that is now in production).

I'm trying to understand the "Update to revision" dialog better to see if I'm missing something, and I realized that I don't quite understand what all the options under "Update Depth" mean. I looked though the TortoiseSVN site, and haven't found any good detail.

Can someone explain the differences between the following options under "Update Depth":

- Working copy
- Fully recursive
- Immediate children, including folder
- Only file children
- Only this item
- Exclude

I think I understand "Immediate children", "Only file children", and "Only this item". But I'm not sure what the difference is between "Working copy", "Fully recursive" and "Exclude" is.

Answer (score 1):

`Working copy` : use the current checkout depth, i.e. don't change anything. If you check more items, those will be checked out fully/recursively.

`Fully recursive` : that folder is checked out and all subfolders and their subfolders and theirs subfolders... i.e.: everything below that folder is checked out

`Exclude` : that folder is not checked out and left empty. Neither files nor folders inside that folder is checked out

If you want to remove a checked out folder, right-click on that folder in the working copy, select "Update to revision" from the context menu and set the depth to `Exclude`

Comment: What I don't understand with "Working copy", is what happens if I use "Working copy", then click on "Choose items", and add checkboxes to several directories I hadn't checked out in the past.

I also can't figure out how to "uncheckout" a part of the tree I used to have checked out.